# how to work with 2 datepicker widgets

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I have two datepickers, one representing start date and another the end date.
I am using angular-ui.
How to make each one to function independently.
**EDIT:**
And also how to make the 2 datepickers to appear on the same line

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uuZuURfWFK8l4baNBlNw?p=preview) is plunkr demo

**HTML code**

```
  <body ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
   <br><br><br>


    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt1" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt1" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
    </div>        





<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maintain separate variable and function for both the datepickers. It should help

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/rGJndx1sXK9u8WCXSMFS?p=preview

JS:

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.today = function() {
      $scope.dt1 = new Date();
      $scope.dt2 = new Date();
    };
    $scope.today();

    $scope.clear = function() {
      $scope.dt1 = null;
      $scope.dt2 = null;
    };

    // Disable weekend selection
    $scope.disabled = function(date, mode) {
      return (mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6));
    };

    $scope.toggleMin = function() {
      $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
    };
    $scope.toggleMin();

    $scope.open1 = function($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();
      $event.stopPropagation();

      $scope.opened1 = true;
    };
    $scope.open2 = function($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();
      $event.stopPropagation();

      $scope.opened2 = true;
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
      formatYear: 'yy',
      startingDay: 1
    };

    $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
    $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    var afterTomorrow = new Date();
    afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
    $scope.events = [{
      date: tomorrow,
      status: 'full'
    }, {
      date: afterTomorrow,
      status: 'partially'
    }];

    $scope.getDayClass = function(date, mode) {
      if (mode === 'day') {
        var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
          var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

          if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
            return $scope.events[i].status;
          }
        }
      }

      return '';
    };
  })
  .controller("mainctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.courses = [{
      "name": "Java",
      "level": "I"
    }, {
      "name": "Python",
      "level": "I"
    }, {
      "name": "Nodejs",
      "level": "A"
    }];
    $scope.caller = function() {
      console.log($scope.inputvalue);


    };

  })
  .filter('inArray', function($filter) {
    return function(list, arrayFilter, element) {
      return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem) {
        return !arrayFilter || arrayFilter.length == 0 || arrayFilter.indexOf(listItem[element]) != -1;
      });
    };
  });
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt1" is-open="opened1" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt2" is-open="opened2" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

I am not sure if this is good way to do but I did it in this way. May be someone can correct me on this.

Answer (score 1):

basically you just need to seperate the scope variable, that opens both datepickers.

```
scope.openFirst = function($event) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  $event.stopPropagation();

  $scope.openedFirst = true;
};
```

You could use the same function for both datepickers too and add an argument to the function.

http://plnkr.co/edit/df0GQfnh4g1Os3DwcK0V?p=preview

This is very rudimentary but can give you the right idea and works.

Answer (score 0):

*just elaborating on K K's comment*

Use different `is-open` attribute and then pass the attribute in through the `ng-click` function.Also use different `ng-models`

```
 <input type="text" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy" ng-model="dt1" is-open="opened1" min="minDate" max="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true"/>
 <button class="btn" ng-click="open($event,'opened1')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></button>
```

inside **controller** add the passing argument

```
$scope.open = function($event,opened) {
$event.preventDefault();
$event.stopPropagation();

$scope[opened] = true;
};
```